# How to get number and insert into a array

Tags: php, arrays

I have something like this => "1,2,3" that I get this from the user (that is just an example because I do not know those numbers)

I want to get those numbers and insert each number into an array like $numbers

```
$numbers['0'] = 1;
$numbers['1'] = 2;
```

how can I do that?

Comment: You can add onto an existing array by using `[]`. Ie: `$numbers[] = 1; $numbers[] = 2;` will produce `array ( 0=> 1, 1=> 2 )`

Comment: the problem is I do not know what those numbers!

Comment: @motmh which numbers?

Comment: Is `"1,2,3"` a string ?

Comment: @ZainFarooq "1,2,3" sorry I am not good enough in English :) I hope you understand what I want

Comment: @RamyHerrira yes I get this from an input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `explode` to split the string by comma and get a array:

```
$str = "1,2,3";
$numbers = explode(",",$str);
print_r($numbers);
```

Which will output,

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

Which is,

```
$numbers[0] = 1;
$numbers[1] = 2;
$numbers[2] = 3;
```

You can copy paste the above code and try here [phptester](http://phptester.net/)

Answer (score 2):

In this case [`explode` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is your friend !

```
$numbers = explode(",", $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. For example if you get user input from `form` which is stored in `$_POST` variable

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $newArray[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($newArray);
```